# Instantiation Errors involving Unordered Map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am getting this error on compile:

"see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Hash,_Alloc,false>>::insert(_Iter,_Iter)'"

This is another error:

'reference to function template instantiation 'void mutable_heap::push(const T &)' being compiled'

This is my push method, I can change the definition but not the parameter. T is a templated value.

```
     void push(const T& value){
        int size = heap.size();   //gets the value of my heap
        heap.push_back(value);   //adds the value to the heap
        heapUp(0);               //calls heapify up method
        map.insert(value,size);  //map is an unordered_map -- insert the
         //value and size
     }
```

Am I doing something wrong with the insert method, here? Or is the error coming from outside this method?

Comment: Can you post the _actual_ error?

Comment: `insert` doesn't work that way. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) for the proper definition.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `map.insert(std::make_pair(value,size));`.

Comment: or `map.insert({value, size});`

Comment: or `map.emplace(value, size);`

Comment: I see now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of map.insert is incorrect.
Try

```
map[value] = size;
```